# Why does my computer make noises?

Tags: hardware, troubleshooting, noise

My computer seems to have troubles with noises. Its a kind of a scratchy, repeated, croaky noise. And it is very disturbing and annoying to the peers around me. I dont know where and how much it is to fix it, and I am pretty sure its expensive.
I dont know the reasons to this noise either.
It may be the fan broken? Some people tell me that something is loose inside and
it may crash my commputer at any moment.

I need help!
Thanks.
Lauren

Comment: can you open your computer ? if so, you could listen which part that noise comes from. It could be your HDD (how old your computer is ? ), or one of fans. But be careful, this may be dangerous. Preferably, don't touch anything inside, just listen.

Or, better, just listen your computer from more sides, without opening. If that sound comes from back top, back rear of front side, or from which side you can hear it better. It will take some time.

Comment: Sorry about the noise in your system, but I don't believe that it is Ubuntu related :/

Comment: Questions like this are probably better on http://superuser.com (But yeah, sounds like a fan, a local shop can probably fix it for relatively cheap, don't take it to Best Buy or a place like that they'll just rip you off)

Answer (score 3):

That's most likely a broken fan, they have the tendency to break the most, cause a lot of noise and are among the only components that can break, but still have your computer working.

So open up your computer, switch it on and listen where the noise comes from. Also just look at all the fans, most likely you can tell already visually that they aren't running smoothly.

How to replace the fan depends on what type of CPU socket you have and which of the fans is broken, i.e. a case fan would be easier to replace then a CPU fan, while a powersupply fan requires a completely new powersupply, if its a HDD fan, you could probably just unplug it without any issue.

Cost shouldn't be that much of an issue, somewhere in the $5-$30.

Comment: It seems that my computers noise comes from the left side, where all the USBs, Hard disks, and charger is plugged from. Lots of people say that it's one of my fans that has been loosened or something. I am not sure what to do . What do you think may be the worst damage and the estimated time it would be?